# Updating index в AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Почистила свой Mac  с помощью CleanMyMac, зашла в AndroidStudio, нажала Run и вот теперь уже минут 50, выдается окошко Updating Index, пробовала закрыть проект и открыть его еще раз, но тоже самое. Кто знает, что делать в такой ситуации?                      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй Build -> Clean Project , Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: @KirillStoianov Clean Project  и Rebuild Project  не  активны сейчас, в меню  Build сейчас активны только   Build Apk

Comment: Пробуй File->Invalidate Caches

Comment: @KirillStoianov Проблема решилась сама собой, прошло 1,5 часа и   AndroidStudio завершила индексацию.

Comment: Всего лишь полтора часа))

Comment: @KirillStoianov   Зато теперь проект быстрее собирается!